# Geoserver - Geofence How to change catalog mode?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-geofence

According to the [**`docs`**](https://github.com/geoserver/geofence/wiki/Main-concepts#constraints) it seems to be possible to change **`the catalog mode`** for a layer using this Geofence plugin.

But I can't find an option, button or something like that, that could do this in `GeoServer page`.

How it is possible to change the catalog mode for a layer in `Geofence`? Is it only possible via REST?

Changing the catalog mode in `Layer Security` section seems to have no effect at all.

I'm using **`GeoServer 2.11-RC1`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule editing page embedded in GeoServer is limited to some basic stuff.

If you need to handle some more advanced filtering (such as catalog mode, CQL r/w access, attribute visibility, and all the other stuff you can see in the doc page) you need to use the GUI of the GeoFence standalone webapp or the REST interface.

Comment: Thank you!! What is the URL of the Geofence webapp?

Comment: Sorry I can't find this section. In Geoserver, once installed Geofence in Security section I have this 3 options: `Geofence`, `Geofence Data Rules` and `Geofence Admin Rules`, but nothing there shows catalog mode, CQL, ... options. So how can I acces to the suggested page? I'm missing something to configure/install?

Comment: When you define a Rule which contains workspace and layer, the "Details" button will become enabled. Once pressed, you will be presented a dialog with all the advanced filtering details, where you can also set the catalog mode.

Comment: Here the links to the pre-built war files:
   https://github.com/geoserver/geofence#getting-geofence
GeoFence should be installed in apache tomacat or some other container, just like GeoServer. Once installed, it will have its own GUI.

Comment: Perfect! that's what I was missing. I had installed only the plugin for goeserver!

Comment: Please note that there are 2 different geofence plugins for geoserver:

- geofence: acts only as a client, and you need the geofence standalone webapp, which features the full-featured rule editor

- geofence-server: runs the geofence engine embedded in geoserver; easier to install, but has limited rule editing capabilities.
The 2 plugins are incompatibile, and you should remove all the jars belonging to one of them, before installing the other one.

Comment: Yes! I have now installed geofence plugin and the standalone webapp, but I still have some doubts about how to configure Geofence (standalone webapp) to get the rules and users from geoserver geofence plugin? Is this possible or should I use the geofence-server instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58516/discussion-between-jose-hermosilla-rodrigo-and-emanuele-tajariol).

Comment: I've been configuring some layer rules in geofence, I tried to put mixed mode for the catalog. I wanted this option to display an alert for login just as geoserver mixed mode does whenever a ``"protected layer"`` is requested. But intead is giving me ``HTTP responses`` with status 200 and this kind of error message in the body ``Could not find layer workspace:layer``. Is there any way to do this with Geofence? If it's possible, Is there any options in the rule form I should fill?